# Pyspark ETL job - How to transform an array of struct to 3 maps

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, etl, aws-glue

I am currently setting up an ETL Glue Job to transform some raw data in json to parquet. I would like to transform an array of struct in my dataframe to 3 maps.

Current structure in the dynamic dataframe:

```
|-- remunerations: array
|    |-- element: struct
|    |    |-- category_id: int
|    |    |-- price_class_1: double
|    |    |-- price_class_2: double
|    |    |-- price_class_3: double
```

Wanted structure:

```
|-- remuneration_price_class_1: map
|    |-- key: int                 # field 'category_id' from the struct
|    |-- value: double            # field 'price_class_1' from the struct
|-- remuneration_price_class_2: map
|    |-- key: int                 # field 'category_id' from the struct
|    |-- value: double            # field 'price_class_2' from the struct
|-- remuneration_price_class_3: map
|    |-- key: int                 # field 'category_id' from the struct
|    |-- value: double            # field 'price_class_3' from the struct
```

Thank you for your support!
Matthieu

Comment: Please update the question with a small sample of your dataframe .

Answer (score 0):

With the following input data:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    IntegerType,
    StructType,
    StructField,
    ArrayType,
    DoubleType,
)

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField(
            "remunerations",
            ArrayType(
                StructType(
                    [
                        StructField("category_id", IntegerType()),
                        StructField("price_class_1", DoubleType()),
                        StructField("price_class_2", DoubleType()),
                        StructField("price_class_3", DoubleType()),
                    ]
                )
            ),
        )
    ]
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        [[(1, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0), (3, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0)]],
        [[(2, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)]],
    ],
    schema=schema,
)
```

You can use the [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) and [`create_map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.create_map.html#pyspark.sql.functions.create_map) functions for this:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = (
    df
        .select(F.explode("remunerations").alias("remunerations"))
        .select(
            F.create_map("remunerations.category_id", "remunerations.price_class_1").alias(
                "remuneration_price_class_1"
            ),
            F.create_map("remunerations.category_id", "remunerations.price_class_2").alias(
                "remuneration_price_class_2"
            ),
            F.create_map("remunerations.category_id", "remunerations.price_class_3").alias(
                "remuneration_price_class_3"
            ),
        )
    )

>>> df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- remuneration_price_class_1: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: integer
 |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- remuneration_price_class_2: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: integer
 |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- remuneration_price_class_3: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: integer
 |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = true)
```